# HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported Spring Security Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Hello I am facing the 'HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported'
exception when trying to do login using spring security.

Following is my code :

pgLogin.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function focusOnLoad() {
        document.getElementById("username").focus();
    }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="focusOnLoad()">
    <div align="center">

        <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                <div>
                    <p style="color: red;">${error}</p>
                </div>
        </c:if>

        <c:if test="${not empty message}">
                <div>
                    <p style="color: red;">${message}</p>
                </div>
        </c:if>

        <c:url var="loginUrl" value="/login" />
        <form action="${loginUrl}" method="post">
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="username">Email</label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="username" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="password">Password</label></td>
                        <td><input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" required></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>

            <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />

            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Log In">
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

DesertLampSecurityConfiguration.java

```
package co.in.desertlamp.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DesertLampSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationMgr) throws Exception {
        authenticationMgr.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("subodh.ranadive@desertlamp.com")
            .password("Dlpl123#")
            .authorities("ROLE_SUPER_USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/home").access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_USER')")
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/loginPage")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/homePage")
                .failureUrl("/loginPage?error")
                .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/loginPage?logout");   
    }
}
```

DefaultController.java

```
package co.in.desertlamp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class DefaultController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("common/pgDefault");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView loginPage(@RequestParam(value = "error",required = false) String error) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        if (error != null) {
            model.addObject("error", "Invalid Email OR Password");
        }

        model.setViewName("common/pgLogin");
        return model;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/home"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView homePage() {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("common/pgWelcome");
        return model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your config as following to match your method handlers:

```
...
.formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks. When I changed the code as per your suggestion, then I 
got 'HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported' when
I navigated to the login page from my default page.

Comment: Did you remove the `@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)`?

Comment: You need two controllers, one for rendering form possibly with form errors and another for handling authentications. Keep the old `@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)` method and add a new one for `POST`.

Comment: Hello, I added two controllers. Please find below code. But now what happens, I am not getting the exception but credentials are not matched and I am getting redirected to the welcome page. What I want to do is once I enter credentials, if the credentials are correct I should get redirected to the welcome page and if credentials are false I should stay on login page with error message.

 @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView handleAuthentication() {
  my logic...
    }

Sorry, I am newbie to spring security so not getting it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for update.

One more thing please, What should be in the method
public ModelAndView handleAuthentication(...) because in controller I have mentioned the "/home" request mapping, so after authentication it will redirect to welcome page. I am confused about what should be in the method because once authentication is done, defaultSuccessUrl is "/home" so in controller when "/home" is matched it well redirect to welcome page.

Thanks.

Comment: Whats your spring security version? 3.x or 4.x?

Comment: My spring version is 4.x.

I have deleted the method and its working complete now.

Thanks a lot. :-)